# Video de Youtube insertado en HTML 5 no esta disponible

Tags: html, html5, vscode

Soy nuevo programando, así que haciendo pruebas, quise insertar un video de youtube en mi código de html, pero cuando lo abro, dice **El video no esta disponible**, probé con muchos  videos y en todos pasa lo mismo, que puede ser? Agradecería la ayuda, acá el código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RckR</title>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe width="860" height="615" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o-YBDTqX_ZU"
      title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
      picture" 
      allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pues acabo de probar tu código en mi servidor local (de mi propio PC) y lo abro con localhost/you.html y me ha funcionado perfectamente. Me sale el Rick Aslhey ese. Pensaba que youtube no permitia iframes pero por lo que sea a mi me funciona. Prueba a ponerlo en un servidor en lugar de ejecutarlo desde vscode a ver que sucede.

Comment: @masterguru te rickrollearon? :P

Comment: @Alfabravo pues no conocia el termino, vaya... y mira que seguramente no es la primera vez, pues ese video estoy arto de verlo de tanto en tanto y ahora creo comprender el porque, je, gracias por el aporte.  (Yo es que soy más de la época del goatse y las nuevas bromas no las entiendo)

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenidx a SOes. Eso obedece a comportamientos de youtube (y de cómo expone su contenido) más que a tu HTML.

Si revisas hilos de [ayuda de Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/20562339/getting-video-unavailable-error-on-an-embedded-url?hl=en) o en StackOverflow [en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969269/embedded-youtube-video-doesnt-work-on-local-server/56419165#56419165), verás que todo pasa por alguna de las siguientes opciones:

- Estás corriendo tu sitio usando alguna IP privada como `192.168.0.1/misitio` y las políticas de YouTube no funcionan bien con ese tipo de URL. Si usas un dominio, va a funcionar.
- El código que genera Youtube para embeber tiene un enlace a `youtube.com/embed/HASH-ID-DEL-VIDEO`. Han reportado muchas veces que esa URL no funciona bien; si usas la URL completa `youtube.com/watch?v=HASH-ID-DEL-VIDEO` en su lugar, este se muestra bien.
- Las configuraciones del video que intentas embeber no permiten que se reproduzca en modo `embed` (o de pronto tiene música con copyright y no se deja usar así). Prueba usando el enlace "normal".